# How to make headers resize for mobile- CSS

Tags: css

My font for my headers is 60px and I am trying to reformat to be able to shrink or make it responsive for mobile so the words are not cut off in the middle of the word.

Thanks very much!

This is the code:

```
h1 {
font-size: 4.286em; /* 60px */
margin-bottom: 24px;
width: auto;
text-align: center;

/* Portrait and Landscape */

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 240px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 240px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: landscape) {

}
```

Comment: Are you aware to the fact that you don't have an enclosing curly synonym to the `H1` element?

Comment: @Alon Yes I thought you leave it open so that the media can be applied to the H1 element?

Comment: No, you need to add specific style for H1 inside each of the media queries (example: `@media only screen .... { h1 { font-size: 2.286em;} }`

Comment: @Alon is correct, you need to close it, and you can also just take the full tag with the styling of the H1 and place it inside the respective media queries and just change the sizes/styling for each individual screen size

Comment: @Torean This still does not seem to be working! Would you be able to message what It should look like? Thanks!!

Comment: @AlannaFournie its interesting that the answer below doesnt work as its suppose to but could you send us the markup you have as well, then we can test and help sort this out for you, its a interesting issues that is suppose to work

Answer (score 0):

You are close, just add the `h1` changes inside each media query, and also you are missing a closing tag on your original `h1` style.

```
h1 {
font-size: 4.286em; /* 60px */
margin-bottom: 24px;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
}
/* Portrait and Landscape */

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 240px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
h1 {
font-size: 4em; /* a little smaller*/
}
}
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 240px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait) {
h1 {
font-size: 3.5em; /* a little smaller*/
}
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: landscape) {
h1 {
font-size: 3em; /* a little smaller*/
}

}
```

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be working on my mobile portrait view. I tried to decrease to a smaller "em" but still no luck. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Check out this website https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ makes sure media queries match the phone you are using. If you still have an issue, tell me the type of phone you are having the problem with and I will build one for you.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is actually make markup using the same media queries you used and just made different background colors for you to know that they all are working. the css below will show you which screen will show which color background based on the screen sizes:

```
    /*This will be anything thats not mobile. it will show a green background*/
body {
    background: green;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 4.286em;
    /* 60px */
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Portrait - portrait devices will be purple based on your dimension*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 240px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 4.286em;
        /* 60px */
        margin-bottom: 24px;
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
/* Landscape - landscape devices will be purple based on your dimension*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    body {
        background: purple;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 4.286em;
        margin-bottom: 24px;
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

---

The HTML I used for this test:

```
<h1>This Is a Heading Tag</h1>
```

---

### Note that you might need to change the demensions a little to make it work for all becuase i noticed that some phones have larger screens than the size you used. e.g- my huawei landscape falls back to green while my iphone 4s landscape falls back to purple but this is just us showing you that your code should work.

What you need to do to emulate is open chrome and the developer tools F12 and you will see when the console opens, on the top left you will see a phone icon, click on that and then your screen will change. you see the drop down of the phones on the top left? choose the phone and the checkbox next to it to get the landscape mode to see the different variations i mentioned ealier.

### Hope this clears, i will gladly help if you need more help. Link to a place i hosted your code update - http://coreb.co.za/lab/design/mediaQueries/

Remember that in essence this style should make anything that's not a mobile landscape or portrait green based on your demensions and then if the demensions are met then you should be able to see the iphone 4 is red and is correct and landscape purple, you just need to make the correct sizes as i mentioned earlier but I'm here to help if need be

Good Luck